# Automated Youtube Playlists From CC-language?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, closed-captions, playlists

If the videos of a certain account to a varying degree have closed captions/subtitles in multiple languages, would it be possible programmatically (or at all) to set up playlists, based on their CC-languages?

I.e. so that all the videos having French subtitles would figure in one playlist, and all that had German in one etc.

(Naturally, some videos might figure in more than one list).

The information exists, as the language of any given CC is specified at upload time. So in principle it ought to be possible .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`captions.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) on the videos in the [list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists) of uploaded videos for that channel and specify `part=snippet` to get the language of the closed captions. From there, you can [`create`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/insert) a playlist based on that closed captions' language and add the video using [`videos.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert). Based on the programming language you'd like to use, you could do this programmatically as well.